# How to pick short video from gallary and Record Short Video using camera in android

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

How to add short video feature in my android app?

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , you need to add the relevant to **Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And in code behind

We could use the plugin [Media.Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) from nuget to implement the function .

```
using Android;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Plugin.Media;
```

Request the permissions when App first loading .

in MainActivity -> on Create

```
if (!(this.CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.Camera) == (int)Permission.Granted))
{
      RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.Camera, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage }, 0);
}
```

**Take Video**

```
    //record video
    private async void RecordVideoButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (this.CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.Camera) == (int)Permission.Granted)
        {
            // We have permission, go ahead and use the camera.

            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
            {
                //"No Camera"
                return;
            }

            // take video
            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakeVideoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreVideoOptions
            {
                Quality = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.VideoQuality.High,
                
            });

            if (file == null)
                return;
        }

        else
        {
            // Camera permission is not granted. If necessary display rationale & request.
            
        }


    }
```

**Pick Video**

```
    //pick video
    private async void PickVideoButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (this.CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.Camera) == (int)Permission.Granted)
        {
            // We have permission, go ahead and use the camera.

            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            // take video
            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickVideoAsync();

            if (file == null)
                return;


        }

        else
        {
            // Camera permission is not granted. If necessary display rationale & request.

        }


    }
```